# How to get the last inserted row from my table ?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created the following table in ORACLE

```
create table test(id number,name varchar2(30));
```

I have inserted the following records.

```
insert into test values (1,'Ronaldo');
insert into test values (2,'Messi');
insert into test values (3,'Bale');
insert into test values (3,'Zlatan');
insert into test values (2,'Neymar');
```

How can I get the last row that I inserted? i.e the o/p should be 2,Neymar
Do we have any query for this?
Please do help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add  timestamp_c column to the table and update create date and time. By sorting this column you can get last inserted record

Comment: Add an auto_increment filed in your table set that field as primary key then you can easily get the last inserted record using max(filed_name)

Comment: There is no such thing as the "last inserted" row in a relational database. Rows in a relational database are unordered sets.

Answer (score 2):

Either you have to create a created_date field or you have to create a auto Number field that is called sequence. Then you have to write below query

select * from test order by created_date desc;
or 
select * from test order by seq_number desc;

First row will be last inserted row in both the cases.

Comment: Thank you Mohd Ahmad. I knew about Primary Key and sequence and I knew how those things work. Do we have any other way to get the last inserted record?

Answer (score 0):

This reference will help and matches most answers and comments on the question
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_find_last_row.htm

Answer (score -1):

CREATE TABLE test (
     id number,
     name   varchar(30),
     distinguish    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);

---

select id , name from test
where   distinguish in (select  max(distinguish) from test)